# Deformation quantization of an integrable system

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, integrable-systems, deformation-quantization

What is known about lifting n Poisson commuting functions on a 2n-dimensional symplectic manifolds (say R^2n) to Moyal-Weyl commuting functions?

Comment: I have replaced the two tags (integrable) and (systems) by the tag ([tag:integrable-systems]). Maybe you wanted to created a tag called ([tag:defomration-quantization]) rather than two separate tags (deformation) and (quantization)? (Since we're talking about tags, it might be worth mentioning that the question has [no top-level tag](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1457).)